# Are usability questions on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question, off-topic, questions

I've come across several questions about usability which I feel would be better asked on uxexchange.com. This raises the slightly tricky issue that uxexchange is an 'old style' SO member - i.e. it doesn't go through the area51 route, but uses Stack Exchange.

What do people feel about usability questions on pro webmasters?

Answer (score 5):

I think usability questions are very much on topic. It is part of our job to identify bottlenecks that keep users from doing whatever we want them to be doing and fix them.

Pro Webmasters is going to have a bit more overlap than most, but only because webmasters tend to wear many hats.

As long as the question fits within the guidelines described in the FAQ, of course. I can imagine that it might be hard to write a question on usability that could conceivably have a single correct answer, but not impossible.

Comment: OK. I guess I feel a bit 'uncomfortable' about overlap, since it splits the audience - right now, which is best to post a question about usability on: uxexchange or webmasters? Or should I just post every question on both? Or should I not worry and hope that I'll get a great answer whichever I post on? Possibly the latter :)

Comment: @Bobby - always avoid cross posting. The FAQ on each site states what is and is not on topic, so just pick the best site / community that you think can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the uxexchange but it doesn't look like a site I would visit or be interested in, so I don't see it as a viable alternative to this site.

Comment: I have the same general feeling when it comes to doctype.com. Strangely, we've yet to see few if any questions that overlap with them. I thought it would be the reverse

Comment: Because of its content or ... something else? Like I say, there is quite a big overlap between the two sites in terms of usability questions.